# Get name of first file in files[] array

Tags: php

I have an array of files posted with `name="files[]"` and id like to take the name of the first file and assign it the variable `$first_file`. When i do `$first_file = $_FILES['files']['name'];` it just returns 'array'.

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r` to see the structure of `$_FILES`.  You should able to figure out how to access the element you want after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy:

```
$_FILES['files']['name'][0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$_FILES['files']['name'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$_FILES['files']['name'][0]
```

By the way, If you want to see all the keys you can do

```
print_r($_FILES['files']['name']);
```